# Make the table headers expand to accept long names in the rows

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">          
    <table class="table" width="100%" >
      <thead>
        <tr>        
           <th class= "style6"  >Year</th>
           <th class="style6"   >Person of The Year</th>
           <th class="style6" >Citizen of the Year</th>              
           <th class="style6"  >Outstanding Service</th>              
           <th class="style6"  >Lifetime Achievement</th>              
           <th class="style6"  >International Category</th>              
           <th class="style6"  >Samantha Young Service Award</th>              
           <th class="style6" >Central Chapter Awards</th>              
           <th class="style6"  >Other Awards</th>              
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="style9">1973</td>
          <td class="style9">Charles Johnson</td>
          <td class="style9">James SMith and Issac Smith</td>
          <td class="style9">&nbsp;</td>
```

In this code I have a responsive table.  When I insert long names in the rows the information moves to the next line. Is there a way I can rework the tables so they expand if needed based on the length of the names across the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `white-space: nowrap;` to the `td`

```css
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

tr {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="style6">Year</th>
          <th class="style6">Person of The Year</th>
          <th class="style6">Citizen of the Year</th>
          <th class="style6">Outstanding Service</th>
          <th class="style6">Lifetime Achievement</th>
          <th class="style6">International Category</th>
          <th class="style6">Samantha Young Service Award</th>
          <th class="style6">Central Chapter Awards</th>
          <th class="style6">Other Awards</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="style9">1973</td>
          <td class="style9">Charles Johnson</td>
          <td class="style9">James SMith and Issac Smith</td>
          <td class="style9">&nbsp;</td>
```